# Creating a linked Array for Shortcuts

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that will check for the path of a shortcut and if it doesn't exist it will create it.I did not want to have a .csv to be needed. So I thought a linked array would work well. The creating of the shortcut works if I do something like this:

`$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$home\desktop\somepath"` but when trying to do this:

> $Shortcut.TargetPath = $Short.Target it will create a blank shortcut
>   that will target "this PC". The naming of the shortcut works just fine
>   but the target location does not.

When I run the script it will place the shortcuts on the desktop and they are all named correctly, but the target locations are not pulling through. Now when I enter $short.target into PowerShell after running the code it will pull up the last bit that was run (as it should) just fine.

```
$short.target

C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools\ptoneclk.exe
```

In addition I am getting `System.Collections.Hashtable.Link is being created` when `Write-Host $Short.Link` bit is run for each one.

What am I missing?

```
$Shortcuts = @(
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Word 2016.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"},
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Excel 2016.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"},
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Outlook 2016.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"},
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"},
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Cisco AnyConnect.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"},
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Cisco Jabber.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Cisco Jabber\CiscoJabber.exe"},
@{Link = "$Home\Desktop\Webex Productivity Tools.lnk" ; Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools\ptoneclk.exe"}
)

Write-Host "Creating shorcuts"

foreach($Short in $Shortcuts)
{
if (Test-Path -path $Short.Link)
 {
   Write-Host "$Short.Link Exists already"
 }
else
{
Write-Host "$Short.Link is being created"
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($Short.Link)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $Short.Target
    $Shortcut.Save()
 }
}
```

Comment: `Write-Host "$($Short.Link) is being created"` this would fix your issue with the output. Take a look here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/. The second part works fine for me, not sure what is wrong

Comment: Can you try replacing `c:\program files (x86)` with `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`? to avoid any potential pathing issues on the system you are running from? also can you verify that your targets are displaying correctly after making the change 4c suggested for your variable expansion in your string?

Comment: 4c the system collections hashtable still shows up BUT since you said that the second part works fine on your system I decided to restart my computer and that fixed the issue. Thanks so much!

Mike: I did try placing in ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} but that did not make a difference at this time. but thank you for the reply

Comment: it definitely shouldn't show up if you do `Write-Host "$($Short.Link) is being created"`

Comment: 4c I ended up clearing it out and copying and pasting your bit in there and it worked fine. No idea. But it seems to be working great now. It lets me know what is being created and the creation part works Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart and following the directions of @4c74356b41 worked great